# API request: better approach to set a Enum value

Tags: javascript, api, enums

The Backend has an end-point called `api/Options/GetEmailMessageTemplate`, it returns objects which has this schema:

```
{
  messageType: string, Enum: [ ConfirmationEmail, 
ConfirmationTransaction, RecoveryPassword, SetupAdminAccount, ConfirmationApiKey, ConfirmationDepositTransaction ]
  language: string, Enum: [ En, Ru, Zh, Es, Et ]
  subject: string,
  template: string,
  isUsed: boolean
}
```

e.g. response:

```js
{
  "messageType": 1,
  "language": "En",
  "subject": "string",
  "template": "string",
  "isUsed": true
}
```

here is another end-point to edit it `api/Options/Options/UpdateEmailMessageTemplate` which consumes json with the same schema as above. `messageType` might be either number of an element in Enum or Enum value (e.g. `'ConfirmationEmail'`)

On the Frontend to list all the data and be able to change it I came up with this approach:

1. I made an strictly ordered array:

```
messageTypes: [  
 { 
    name: 'Confirmation Email',
    success: false,
 },
...
]
```

Success is required to show if the change of this template was successful

2. I get `messageType`as a number id from backend, I just used it as index in my array (so, for this to work my array must be ordered in the exactly same way Enum of that field is ordered ), to get the name of that `messageType` and operate with `success` field

3.`api/Options/Options/UpdateEmailMessageTemplate` gets `messageType` using index of the currently being edited element (`indexOf`)

While this approach worked as was expected I can't help but think there was a better way to handle this.

I would like to hear if there are better practices to handle that

Comment: So you are just trying to translate the return from number to enum string and vise/versa?

Comment: @mwilson I was trying to link `messageType` server returns with the array on the frontend I need to show, id as 3rd field would probably better, but using strictly ordered array with `indexOf` to find an idex and use that index as id seemed shorter. Now I just wonder were there better approaches, something different from putting id as 3rd field in my array

Comment: Not 100% clear still. So the server returns an object with a property of `messageType` (which is a number). But, you have a known 'friendly values' list that matches it and you want to be able see the string translation of the `number` `messageType`?

Comment: @mwilson yes, almost what I was need, it was required to make a way to edit it and send back to the server as well so there was a need to make a way to translate it back to that `messageType` number. And it's not exactly friendly value list, it's just C# Enum, Enum key and the value assigned to this key can be both parameters server will understand and process

Comment: Yea, pretty typical use case. Backend required the message type id, whereas you want to work with both values on the front end. If you were using TypeScript, there's a super straightforward way to do this (using TypeScript Enums)

Comment: I would say that the frontend should not be so intimately familiar with the backend(the frontend shouldn't know about the order of the enum of the backend ect).  IMO this would be considered an example of coupling that could be avoided by using an object or Higher Order Function to handle the abstraction.   Metaphorically "You don't tell the waiter 'I want a cheese burger cooked on a flattop grill at 165 degrees for 3.5 min on each side then covered to melt the cheese and ....'  IE you are abstracted from the implementation as the front end should be from the backend.

Comment: And as mwilson suggested you can use classes if the object oriented approach is more your thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding, you are wanting a way to work with a friendly list of values as well as their id's. One approach would be to create two separate `classes`. This would enable you to feed the raw response to a single model and you can add whichever methods are needed to translate `id` > `name` or the other way around.

You could probably get a little more fancier and use `get`/`set` but I'm still a little foggy on the requirements. But, here's an approach that I would take:

```js
/**
 * Create a class that knows how to translate it
 * Bonus points: this could be populated via your endpoint
 * that returns your enum list so you don't have to keep
 * updating it if there's a change on the backend
 */
class MessageType {
  constructor(messageType) {
    this.id = messageType;
    const messageTypes = [
      'ConfirmationEmail',
      'ConfirmationTransaction',
      'RecoveryPassword',
      'SetupAdminAccount',
      'ConfirmationApiKey',
      'ConfirmationDepositTransaction'
    ];
    this.name = messageTypes[this.id];
  }
}

/**
 * Create a class / model for your response.
 * This will enable you to add any methods
 * needed for translating things how you need
 * them. For example, you might want a method
 * to convert your model into what the backend
 * expects.
 */
class MessageTemplate {
  constructor(response) {
    this.messageType = new MessageType(response.messageType);
    this.language = response.language;
    this.subject = response.subject;
    this.template = response.template;
    this.isUsed = response.isUsed;
  }
  getJsonPayloadForBackend() {
    const payload = { ...this };
    payload.messageType = payload.messageType.id;
    return payload;
  }
}

// Usage

const template = new MessageTemplate({
  "messageType": 2,
  "language": "En",
  "subject": "string",
  "template": "string",
  "isUsed": true
});

console.log(template);
console.log('data to send to backend', template.getJsonPayloadForBackend())
```

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for this but is there a clever realisation without using class? Also, what it would be like if there weren't those 'friendly values'?

Comment: TBH, I work the same stack. C# on the back end, JS (actually TS) on the front end. I like to have everything match the back end. So in your case, if the backend is giving you that enum list, I would expect the exact same model to be implemented in TS / JS on the front end so that there is absolutely zero confusion when it comes to what you're working with. Obviously keeping things in sync comes with some pain points, but there's answers to those things out there. I'd also take a look at how TS does enums and how it translates to js (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html)